# Error with graphics gnuplot

Tags: linux, bash, graph, timestamp, gnuplot

I'm programming a graph with axes (y "%" and x "date") and when less than 7 records have not shown well

These are the files

data.csv:

```
20-04-2016 96.8  95.8 100
21-04-2016 97.07 97.99 100
22-04-2016 98.05 99.5 100
23-04-2016 98.64 97.88 100
24-04-2016 98.96 98.99 100
25-04-2016 98.68 98.11 100
```

graph

```
reset

set terminal png size 1200,500

#set xlabel "Time (days)"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y"


set ylabel "Total Petitions (%)"
set yrange [95:100]

set title "Akamai"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set style data linespoints

plot "datos.csv" using 1:2 title "One (%)", \
"" using 1:3 title "Two (%)", \
"" using 1:4 title "Ideal (%)"
```

He shows me this

[image]

As shown, the dates are repeated, and I want one date per record appears.

I also like to put the date

```
%d-%m\n%Y
```

This is solved if I put 7 or more records

And this happens if I put the full date but the description of the axis x

[image]

It could put the date vertically?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `set format x`;

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced color dashed \
rounded size 1200,500

set title "Akamai"
set xlabel "date"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y"
set format x "%d/%m\n%Y"
set xtics 86400
set nomxtics
set ylabel "Total Petitions (%)"
set yrange [95:100]
set style data linespoints
set grid
set key right bottom
set output 'user1847844.png'

plot "datos.csv" using 1:2 title "One (%)", \
"" using 1:3 title "Two (%)", \
"" using 1:4 title "Ideal (%)"
```

Internally, `gnuplot` converts datetimes to seconds. So the line `set xtics 86400` basically says to make one tick per day since one day has 24*60*60 = 86400 seconds. The `set nomxtics` tells gnuplot to not show minor tick marks on the x-axis.

This gives:
[image: corrected PNG image]

If you want to rotate the label, use:

```
set format x "%d/%m/%Y"
set xtics rotate 86400
```

That should format the dates as a single line and rotate the labels by 90 degrees.

**Update:**

Note that I'm using the `pngcairo` terminal. This is based on the [cairo graphics library](http://www.cairographics.org/). This is designed to give consistent output on all output media. But `gnuplot` must be compiled with cairo support for this to work.

In general, I prefer the `pdfcairo` terminal. This produces PDF output which can be scaled without giving pixellation effects.

**Update 2:**

To get consistency in my graphs, I've defined certain styles in my `gnuplotrc`, which I use in my graphs. The contents of my gnuplotrc are shown below.

```
set encoding utf8

# See https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes
# Line styles (colorbrewer Set1)
set style line 1 lc rgb '#E41A1C' pt 1 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # red
set style line 2 lc rgb '#377EB8' pt 6 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # blue
set style line 3 lc rgb '#4DAF4A' pt 2 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # green
set style line 4 lc rgb '#984EA3' pt 3 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # purple
set style line 5 lc rgb '#FF7F00' pt 4 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # orange
set style line 6 lc rgb '#FFFF33' pt 5 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # yellow
set style line 7 lc rgb '#A65628' pt 7 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # brown
set style line 8 lc rgb '#F781BF' pt 8 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # pink
# Palette
set palette maxcolors 8
set palette defined ( 0 '#E41A1C', 1 '#377EB8', 2 '#4DAF4A', 3 '#984EA3',\
4 '#FF7F00', 5 '#FFFF33', 6 '#A65628', 7 '#F781BF' )

# Standard border
set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1 lw 3
set border 0 back ls 11
set tics out nomirror

# Standard grid
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12
unset grid
```

And I use a `pdfcairo` terminal as standard, like this.

```
set terminal pdfcairo enhanced color dashed font "Alegreya, 14" \
rounded size 16 cm, 9.6 cm
```

The font used is an example. For graphs in reports I tend to use the same font as the body text.

The `plot` command uses the defined styles.

```
plot "user1847844.d" using 1:2 ls 1 title "One (%)", \
"" using 1:3 ls 2 title "Two (%)", \
"" using 1:4 ls 3 title "Ideal (%)"
```

This produces a figure looking like this.
[image: graph with my settings]

---

*Note:* Since StackOverflow doesn't accept PDF images, I converted it to a PNG using ImageMagick.

```
convert -density 300 <input.pdf> -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 <output.png>
```